# Unable to paste copied image from light shot in xamarin forms entry control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.windows

I have a requirement of able to paste copied text and images in xamarin forms entry control. I have faced issue while copy image from light shot(it's a software for taking screenshots - it's have a feature like able to copy screenshot image.) in entry control. If I take a screenshot using light shot and copied that image for past in entry control but the past option is not enabled (you can find in image1) while right-clicking in the entry. If I copy any text and try to past that text, paste option is enabled (you can find in image2) in entry control. Please suggest any idea how can I paste images in the entry field. Thank you.

image1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aejHV.png

image2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gCMh.png

Answer (score 0):

Can't paste images or any other kind of binary data into Xamarin Entry.
you need to write your own entry component which will be able to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any sample code regarding paste images in xamarin entry.